# OpenCV Fillpoly Assertion failed

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I want to fill a certain area of my mask. My code looks like this =

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

     while 2>1:
        with mss.mss() as sct:
            monitor = {"top": 360, "left": 810, "width": 650, "height": 475}
            output = "sct-{top}x{left}_{width}x{height}.png".format(**monitor)
            # Grab the data
            sct_img = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
            shap = sct_img.shape
            mask = np.zeros_like(sct_img)
            pts = np.array([[1, 3], [4, 8], [1, 9]], np.int32)
            cv2.fillPoly(mask, pts, 255)

            cv2.imshow("OPENCV/NUMPY normal", mask)

            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break
```

I get the error:

```
cv2.fillPoly(mask, pts, 255) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-k8sx3e60\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2395: error: (-215:Assertion failed) p.checkVector(2, CV_32S) >= 0 in function 'cv::fillPoly'
```

Comment: try np.uint8 in place of np.int32

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d96/tutorial_basic_geometric_drawing.html) example, you have to pass pts as a `list`type:

```py
cv.fillPoly(img, [ppt], (255, 255, 255), line_type) # ppt is an ndarray
```

Therefore, if you pass the `pts` as `[pts]`, the problem should be solved.

```py
cv2.fillPoly(mask, [pts], 255)
```

Comment: I had to write (255,255,255) instead of 255 to get white. I left pts as pts

Comment: That's true, when you set `255` means [255, 0, 0] which means display only blue color.